# Adding multiple columns to a table in LINQ based on a composite class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table in LINQ to SQL.

I would like to define the following class:

```
class Example {
 public string Name;
 public int Value;
}
```

and include several instances of it in my table, like so:

```
[Column]
Example First;

[Column]
Example Second;
```

So that the table actually has four columns:

```
First.Name
First.Value
Second.Name
Second.Value
```

Then be able to populate this table with rows of data.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `Linq2SQL` does not support `Complex Type` properties.

The best way to do this is to take all your `Linq2SQL` code, and bin it. Then replace it with `Entity Framework`.

However, I am not sure that is entirely possible either. Given the column name is on the `Complex Type`, having multiple instances of the complex type in the signature of your entity would produce multiple columns with the same name.

Not good.

Finally, it feels very much like your database schema is a WTF here. Are you sure for EACH AND EVERY entity you will have TWO AND NOT LESS THAN TWO of your complex type from now until the end of time? If you cannot make that guarantee, I am certain you are denormalizing your database and you will tomorrow find a need to create an entity with Three (or maybe One) of your complex type properties.